# gsutil / gcloud storage list files by limits and pagination

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Is there any way we can list files from GCS bucket with limits.

Say I have 2k objects in my bucket. But when I do gsutil ls, I only want the 1st 5 objects, not all.
How to achieve this.

Also is there any pagination available ?
gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/test_file_03102021* 2>/dev/null | grep -i ".txt$" || :

Answer (score 1):

From looking at `gsutil help ls`, `gsutil` doesn't currently have an option to limit the number of items returned from an `ls` call.

While you could pipe the results to something like `awk` to get only the first 5 items, that would be pretty wasteful if you have lots of objects in your bucket (since `gsutil` would continue making paginated HTTP calls until it listed all N of your objects).

If you need to do this routinely on a bucket with lots of objects, you're better off writing a short script that uses one of the GCS client libraries. As an example, check out the [google-cloud-storage Python library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) -- specifically, see [the list_blobs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/_modules/google/cloud/storage/client.html#Client.list_blobs) method, which accepts a `max_results` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pagination available when you use the API directly. If you want only the 5 first objects and you use gsutil, you will have to wait the full answer of hundreds (thousands, millions,...) of files before getting only the first 5.

If you use the API you can do this

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \ 
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<BUCKET_NAME>/o?alt=json&&maxResults=5" \ 
  | jq .items[].name
```

Of course, you can change the max results size

You can include prefix also when you filter. More detail in the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list)